# Is the probability of the union of events nondecreasing in the probability of the events?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, functions

Can it be shown that the probability $P(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$ is nondecreasing in the probability of any event $A_i$?

This fact seems intuitive to me, independent of the fact whether $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are intersecting or not?

So, if for any $A_i$, the probability $P(A_i)$ weakly increases, will the probability $P(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$  weakly increase?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nondecreasing as a function of *sets,* i.e., if one of the events $A_i$ is replaced with a superset then the probability cannot decrease. But the probability $P(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n)$ is not even a *function* of the individual probabilities $P(A_i)$ as numbers, let alone a nondecreasing function of them.

Here is a counterexample in $[0,1]$ with the uniform probability measure. We have $P([0,\frac12]\cup[\frac12,1])>P([0,\frac12]\cup[0,\frac23])$ even though $P([\frac12,1])<P([0,\frac23]).$

*(updated to answer question in comment)*

In the special case where we are given independent $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ and every $A_i$ is an intersection of some of the $E_j$:

$$A_i=\bigcap_{j\in K_i}E_j,\ i=1,\ldots,n$$

let us demonstrate that $P[\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i]$ depends on $P[E_k]$ nondecreasingly. Fix $k$ and let $I=\{i|1\leq i\leq n, k\in K_i\},$ $J=\{i|1\leq i\leq n, k\not\in K_i\}.$

For $i\in I$ write

$$A_i'=\bigcap_{j\in K_i\setminus\{k\}}E_j$$

Then we have

$$\eqalign{
\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i&=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\cup\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\\
&=\left(E_k\cap\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i'\right)\cup\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\\
&=\left(E_k\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i'\setminus\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\right)\right)\sqcup\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\\
P\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right]&=P[E_k]P\left[\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i'\setminus\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\right]+P\left[\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\right]\\
}$$

where in the last line we have used independence, and the symbol $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union. But the expression on the right is clearly nondecreasing in $P[E_k].$

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes perfect sense. 
But maybe let me rephrase my question again slightly. What I want to show is the following: If the probability of an event $P(A_i)$ is nondecreasing, can it be shown that $P(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$ is nondecreasing? This could help me to show monotonicity of a more complex function, I think. Does my question make sense to you?

Comment: The probability $P(A_i)$ is nondecreasing in what parameter? You should really specify what kinds of variations of $A_i$ you have in mind. If the set $A_i$ is allowed to vary arbitrarily then my example shows that you cannot conclude anything for the probability of the union. If the set $A_i$ can only grow *as a set,* i.e., if we only add elements without taking any others away then see my statement about supersets.

Comment: You are right. So let me explain (hopefully) more throughly. What I fundamentally have, are independent events, say $E_1, \dots, E_m$, where each event has a certain probability. The previously mentioned events $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are now intersections of events from $E_1, \dots, E_m$. So, as a result, events $A_1, \dots, A_n$ might be overlapping. What I really want to know is, if the probability of event $E_i$ is increased (recall that $E_i$ might be part of several $A_j$), will the probability $P(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$ increase? Is that question clear to you? Does it make sense?

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks a lot! 

Two short follow-up questions:
1. If the union $A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n$ has been re-written as $\overline{A_1} \cup \dots \cup \overline{A_n}$, then it makes sense to state that, increases (resp. decreases) in $P(E_j)$ lead to increases (resp. decreases) in $P(\overline{A_1} \cup \dots \cup \overline{A_n})$. So, $P$ is increasing in $P(E_j)$(???) ?

2. Can you refer me to a text book that shows that $A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n$ can always be re-written as $\overline{A_1} \cup \dots \cup \overline{A_n}$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It would really be great if you could point me to source which shows how the union of $A_i$ as an intersection of the subfamily of $E_j$ could be transformed into a disjoint union of $\overline{A_i}$ as an intersection of the subfamily of $E_j$. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, that comment was incorrect and I have deleted it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your effort! But I am not sure about the third step of your argument.
$$\eqalign{
&=\left(E_k\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i'\setminus\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i\right)\right)\sqcup\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i}$$
To my understanding the rule you apply shall be $P[A \cup B] = P[(A\setminus B) \sqcup (B \setminus A) \sqcup (A \cap B)]$. But then, I guess there is some part missing in the third step above? Does that make sense?

Comment: In the third step I am using $A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\sqcup B$ as sets, no probabilities involved.

Comment: Ok sure, makes perfect sense! Sorry for the confusion. And thanks a lot for those efforts! Question: Is there a possibility to cite that proof somehow?

Comment: Sure, all SE content is creative commons. For attribution rules see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ but you may have to re-interpret that if it's for a paper publication.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ measurables sets, and $B_i=A_i\cup E_i$.

Then, since $A_i\subseteq B_i$

$\begin{eqnarray}
&&P(B_1\cup B_2\cup...\cup B_n)-P(A_1\cup A_2\cup...\cup A_n)\\
&=&P(\bigcup B_i\backslash\bigcup A_i)\\
&=&P(\bigcup B_i\cap(\bigcup A_i)^c)\\
&=&P\left(\bigcup B_i\cap(\bigcap A_i^c)\right)\\
&=&P\left(\bigcup [B_i\cap(\bigcap A_i^c)]\right)\\
&=&P\left(\bigcup [E_i\cap(\bigcap A_i^c)]\right)\\
&=&P(\bigcup E_i\backslash(\bigcup A_i)^c)\\
&\le&P(\bigcup E_i)\\
&\le&P(E_1)+...+P(E_n)
\end{eqnarray}$

So, by the second and last line, $$0\le P(B_1\cup...\cup B_n)-P(A_1\cup...\cup A_n)\le P(E_1)+...+P(E_n).$$

This shows that $P$ is increasing and "continuos"